# How to take the corresponding value while maximizing with dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following df in R:

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | blue |
| A | 350 | red |
| B | 500 | green. |
| B | 150 | yellow |

With dplyr I want to group the df voor Column_A, taking the max of Column_B and the corresponding value of Column_C (so the value of Column_C where B = max). I right now have the following code:

```
df_new <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(Column_A) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(
    Max_B = max(Column_B),
    Corresponding_C = which.max(Column_B))
```

However, this gives the wrong values for Column_C, because it says that which.max(Column_B) = 1 for all values. How can I change this code that I get the correct values for Column_C?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Others have given you correct solutions.  The reason your code doesn't work is that `summarise` reduces the input data frame to one row per group.  So the concept of "which row in the input data frame supplies the maximum" has no meaning within the `summarise` call.

Comment: Instead of `summarize()` you could use `filter()`: df |> dplyr::filter(Column_B == max(Column_B), .by = Column_A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df %>% group_by(Column_A) %>% slice(which.max(Column_B))
```

Edit : even better, dplyr now has slice_max function

```
df %>% group_by(Column_A) %>% slice_max(Column_B)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `group_by` and `summarise` the `max` value and the color corresponding to the max value using `which.max` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Column_A) %>%
  summarise(max_value = max(Column_B),
            Column_C = Column_C[which.max(Column_B)])
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Column_A max_value Column_C
#>   <chr>        <int> <chr>   
#> 1 A              350 red     
#> 2 B              500 green.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Column_A = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
                 Column_B = c(100, 350, 500, 150), 
                 Column_C = c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow"))

df %>%
  group_by(Column_A) %>%
  filter(Column_B == max(Column_B)) %>%
  distinct(Column_A, .keep_all = TRUE)
```